# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, primevue

I'm using Vue 3-Typescript and primevue
I recently added primevue to my application and I received the error and warnings below.  I am trying to use the primevue '**Menubar**' component when I get the error.  When I use the megamenu component, the error is gone.  I've been looking at this and trying different things for an hour and can't figure out what I'm missing.  Here's the vue component [file](https://github.com/isogunro/my-app/blob/main/src/components/MyPrimeComponents.vue) in my repo.  Here's the [main.ts](https://github.com/isogunro/my-app/blob/main/src/main.ts) file also.  Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *use* before *mount*

```js
app.use(PrimeVue);
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: You're right, but in my case i'm using createSSRApp, is primevue working with SSR ?

Comment: additional note: for anyone who needs to know the import statement at the top of this file should look like this  import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

Answer (score 0):

In case of SSR NuxtJS, Create a file like primevue.js under the plugins directory for the configuration.

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import Button from "primevue/button";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true });
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("Button", Button);
  //other components that you need
});
```